# How to make a space between two side without space-between

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I'm making a responsive menu,

```html
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexFlow: "row wrap" }}>
        {/* left side */}
        <div key="1">nav 1</div>
        <div key="2">nav 2</div>
        <div key="3">nav 3</div>
        {/* left side */}

        {/* right side */}
        <div key="4">nav 4</div>
        <div key="5">nav 5</div>
        <div key="6">nav 6</div>
        {/* right side */}
      </div>
```

I want to have a space between two sides but it still can wrap with each single element.

Something like this: [image]

I have no idea for this, thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use `space-between`?

Comment: space-between make the items have the same space between every item, right? it's can be left, right side as the picture

Comment: correct, If I am understood your question correctly, you want to have auto wrap for divs and have same space between those divs right?

Comment: I want they to have the same space between only when reached breakpoint

Comment: Then use media query for the reached breakpoint

Comment: is it if you can wrap an extra `div` between those divs?

Comment: So how can I split them into two-part when normal?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/51Lsejmo/

Comment: No, the problem is when you wrap, it's wrapped into two rows with 3 items of each, I don't want it

Comment: Honestly I think you should look at using CSS grid, using `gap` along with `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, <size>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject a pseudo element inside the wrapper and set its `order` so that it is placed between 3rd and 4th div; and set `flex-grow: 1`:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#wrapper > div:nth-child(-n + 3) {
  order: 1;
  background-color: papayawhip;
}
#wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  order: 2;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
#wrapper > div:nth-child(n + 4) {
  order: 3;
  background-color: palegoldenrod;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- left -->
  <div key="1">nav 1</div>
  <div key="2">nav 2</div>
  <div key="3">nav 3</div>
  <!-- right -->
  <div key="4">nav 4</div>
  <div key="5">nav 5</div>
  <div key="6">nav 6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I'm using float: left/right instead of flex. Try resizing the browser to see the result.
Here's a fiddle to play around: https://jsfiddle.net/x7f2pvn9/

```css
div.wrapper div {
  display: inline;
  background: red;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 50px;
}

div.left {
  float: left;
}

div.right {
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div.right {
    float: left;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="left">1</div>
    <div class="left">2</div>
    <div class="left">3</div>


    <div class="right">4</div>
    <div class="right">5</div>
    <div class="right">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it seems right, but I'm using flex